# Declaring a global device array using a pointer with cudaMemcpyFromSymbol

Tags: cuda

When I use the following code, it shows the correct value 3345.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

__device__ int d_Array[1];

__global__ void foo(){
    d_Array[0] = 3345;
}

int main()
{
    foo<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    int h_Array[1];
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_Array, d_Array, sizeof(int));
    std::cout << "values: " << h_Array[0] << std::endl;
}
```

But if we replace the line of code `__device__ int d_Array[1];` by
`__device__ int *d_Array;` it shows a wrong value. Why?

Comment: Not sure, just asking...what about memory allocation then?

Comment: You have to call cudaMalloc to allocate d_Array before calling the kernel if you are using the d_Array pointer

Comment: This is misuse of arrays and pointers in C.  It is not specific to CUDA.  If you use `cuda-memcheck` or proper cuda error checking, you will discover that the code using the pointer (only) is illegal.  The code in the kernel is dereferencing an invalid pointer in the illegal case.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in memory allocation. Try the same thing on C++ (on host) and  you will either get an error or unexpected value.
In addition, you can check the Cuda errors calling `cudaGetLastError()` after your kernel. In the first case everything is fine, and the result is `cudaSuccess`. In the second case there is `cudaErrorLaunchFailure` error. Here is the explanation of this error (from cuda toolkit documentation):

"An exception occurred on the device while executing a kernel. Common causes include dereferencing an invalid device pointer and accessing out of bounds shared memory. The device cannot be used until cudaThreadExit() is called. All existing device memory allocations are invalid and must be reconstructed if the program is to continue using CUDA."

Answer (score 0):

Note that cudaMemcpyToSymbol also supports the offset parameter for array indexing